# Pronouncing ɛ̃: are there variants?

Tags: prononciation, phonétique, voyelles, nasalisation

I'm confused by ɛ̃, as in *pain*, *vin*, *cinq*, etc.

Often, and that's what I'm taught, you are told to pronounce it as the *a* in "and".

- [cinq](http://fr.forvo.com/word/cinq/#fr) (first pronunciation)

However, sometimes it is pronounced very differently in my ears. Vin is such a word.

- [vin](http://fr.forvo.com/word/vin/#fr) (first)

To me, the ɛ̃ is pronounced differently in these two cases. Could someone please enlighten me on how things are?

Comment: In what people would generally consider to be a "standard" French accent, these vowels are ostensibly "the same vowel"-- as you say, pronounced something like the "a" of "and", "amplitude" in British English (i.e. where the "a" vowel is stressed and occurs before a nasal consonant, so is nasalised). Here are "vin" and "cinq" pronounced by the same speaker: http://www.french-linguistics.co.uk/how-to-pronounce/cinq-adb2143d9bbdbc33/ http://www.french-linguistics.co.uk/how-to-pronounce/vin-26f9da629e576b03/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There definitely are variants in the pronunciation of that sound. It depends on things like the age of the speaker and where they come from. I don't hear that much difference between the two examples you link, but truthfully I don't have a very good ear for differences between sounds. However, the phoneme /ɛ̃/ of French is usually realized quite a bit lower (closer to an "a" sound) than the vowel phoneme /ɛ/ (and depending on your dialect of English, possibly lower than the sound in "and" as well, so that's not a great reference point). The phonetic sound is often transcribed [æ̃], which is closest to a nasalized version of the sound in the English word "lad" or "lab".

Comment: That's interesting. Here is an audio file that emphasize the difference I hear. It's the word vin. Which do you think sound more correct? Or is either fine? 

https://clyp.it/lgc5ygcf

Comment: I think the first of the pair sounds better -- the second sounds a little too close to /ɑ̃/ to me. However, I am not a native speaker, so you might want some input from one of them as well. If you want to get input from more people, it might help if you de-accepted my answer; I wouldn't mind. Of course, if you're satisfied now you can leave the accept as well.

Comment: I don't think this question is getting anymore attention. Thank you for your time.