# Prononciation des mots "beau" et "bon"

Tags: prononciation, phonétique, voyelles, nasalisation

Dans un extrait de ["La phonétique"](https://archive.org/stream/laphonetique0000malm) de Bertil Malmberg, l'auteur indique que:

> Ainsi les mots *beau* et *bon*, *fait* et *fin* ne se distinguent l'un et l'autre que par la présence ou l'absence de résonance nasale dans la voyelle.

C'est évident que [théoriquement](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/13770/4082), la seule différence entre la prononciation de "fait" et celle de "fin" est la nasalisation de la voyelle. Cependant, je ne vois pas comment la différence entre "beau" et "bon" est similaire: on prononce "beau" comme /bo/ et "bon" comme /bɔ̃/.

Cet exemple est-il complètement inexact? Y a-t-il une variation de la prononciation dont cette assertion est correcte?

Comment: À mon avis  ce n'est qu'une question de notation, le livre de phonétique du français (récent) dont je me sers habituellement note la nasale /ō/ et non  /ɔ̃/.  Voir aussi [Henriette Walter](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henriette_Walter) sur [Martinet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Martinet) : [l’existence
de 4 voyelles nasales /ɛ̃/, /œ̃, /ã/, /õ/](https://www.cairn.info/revue-la-linguistique-2009-2-page-145.htm). Mais je ne suis pas spécialise de la phonétique donc il vaut mieux laisser un spécialiste faire une réponse plus circonstanciée.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comme l'a commenté Laure, la nasale *on* n'est pas toujours retranscrite comme étant ouverte. Les variations individuelles et régionales y sont sûrement pour quelque chose, comme avec le *o* final de *beau* qui, en Belgique, dans l'Est de la France et parfois aussi en [Provence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OLhqh98qV4s), peut être ouvert.

Bertil Malmberg a peut-être été influencé par Raimu pour la prononciation de *beau* ;-)

Answer (score -3):

Ce que l'auteur doit très certainement avoir en tête lorsqu'il écrit « ne se distinguent l'un de l'autre que par … » c'est que la position des organes de la parole dans la bouche sont les mêmes pour les deux sons, il n'y a pas de différence et c'est seulement l'ouverture ou la fermeture des fosses nasales qui décide de quel son il s'agit, l'ouverture correspondant à un son nasal. Voir [La cavité nasale, p. 104 de *Résonance sonore
et cavités supralaryngées*](http://www2.lpl-aix.fr/~ghio/Doc/Bib-2007-chap8.resonance_sonore-Ghio.pdf).